# How to tell wget to download files with url encoded names?

Tags: wget, character-encoding

I'm trying to download an entire website using `wget` and this is the command I use:

```
wget --recursive --no-clobber --page-requisites --convert-links --domains example.com --no-parent  http://www.example.com/en/
```

It's working just fine but there is one problem. There files (mainly images) that their name contains Chinese characters like this:

> [http://www.example.com/path/to/首页主KV3.jpg](http://www.example.com/path/to/%E9%A6%96%E9%A1%B5%E4%B8%BBKV3.jpg)

After downloading the file has been save with this name:

> ??%96页主KV3.jpg

And it's addressed in the html page like this and therefore issuing a 404 error:

> �%2596页主KV3.jpg

I wonder how can I prevent this inconsistency?!

Answer (score 0):

I fought with this today as well.

In my case the problem was with German letters like `ä,ö,ü`

I fixed it by setting all my language settings to `UTF-8`.

You can see a tutorial here:

https://perlgeek.de/en/article/set-up-a-clean-utf8-environment